# Why is 2|p^2 = 2|p?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I trying to get into math with the book "Real Analysis" from Jay Cummings. This is an example where he proves that the root of $2$ is irrational.

It says $2q^2 = p^2$ that implies $2|p^2$, hence
$2|p$. Why is that so? When I divide through $p^2$ I get $\frac{2q^2}{p^2} = 0$ does that imply $2|p^2$? And why does the exponent disappear afterwards ($\rightarrow 2|p$)?

Thank you!

Comment: Please use MathJax to format mathematics, not plaintext. [Here is a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/742).

Comment: Why? Because $2$ is a prime. For every prime, $p\mid xy$ implies $p\mid x$ or $p\mid y$. This is one possible definition of a prime element. So $2\mid x^2$ implies $2\mid x$ or $2\mid x$ - well, that's just $2\mid x$.

Comment: Alternatively, if $2|p^2$ then $2|p$.  Consider the cases where $p$ is even and where $p$ is odd.  That should clarify matters.

Comment: Another way to say this is that if $p^2$ is even, then so is $p$. You can prove this by noting that the square of an odd number is odd.

Comment: Don't use $=$ for logic equivalence. Just write "if and only if" or "iff" for short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if $2|p^2$ then $2|p$.

Why?

simple:
if $p$ is odd then $p^2$ is odd.

proof:
$p=2k+1\implies p^2=4k^2+4k+1=2(2k^2+2k)+1$

thus it is a truth of logic that:

$p^2$ even $\implies p$ even.

Answer (score 0):

One argument is a tautology, essentially:
By (many/most) definitions of a prime, p is a prime if $p|a b$ iff( definition) p|a, or p|b. It then follows from $p|a^2; a^2=aa$ ,that $p|a$ or $p|a$, hence $p|a$.

Comment: Why is it a tautology?

Comment: @DietrichBurde: It's a stament of the form " A or A". Then A follows. If " It rains or it rains", then it certainly rains.

Comment: Ah, you mean the second part, i.e., if $p\mid a\cdot a$, then etc. I thought of the whole claim, which just follows by a definition of a prime element, and not by tautology.